# How plane mirror reflects light so smoothly at a certain direction?

Tags: friction, reflection

We say that "no surface is totally plane,at microscopic level there is some high points and low points,that causes friction".
If we apply this theory to plane mirror, we conclude that plane mirror is not actually *super plane* at the microscopic level.
My question is :then, How plane mirror reflects light so smoothly at a certain direction? Shouldn't light disperse at random direction because of microscopic hill-like structure of mirror?

Comment: This depends on the ratio between the roughness of the surface and the wavelength of the light. When surface imperfections are smaller than the wavelength of the incident light you basically get specular (mirror-like) reflection.

Comment: @Paul . Is there any law/relationship/formula ? And how to measure roughness of something?

Comment: What kind of formula are you looking for? You can define the surface roughness as the standard deviation of the surface imperfections divided by the wavelength of the incident light. There are also formula for the intensity of reflected light as a function of the angle of incidence for a perfectly diffuse medium ([Lambert's cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law)).